# Nginx rewrite rule is adding port in url redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have below rewrite rule in the nginx.conf

```
rewrite "^/licenses/GPL-3$" /licenses/gpl3 permanent;
```

Accessing http://domain_name/licenses/GPL-3 is redirecting the page to http://domain_name:8080/licenses/gpl3.

I dont need the port in the url redirection. http://domain_name/licenses/GPL-3 should redirect to http://domain_name/licenses/gpl3

Comment: You could turn off the port feature with [`port_in_redirect off;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect)

Comment: port_in_redirect off; did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The below modification to the rewrite rule worked.

```
rewrite "^/licenses/GPL-3$" $scheme://$http_host/licenses/gpl3 permanent;
```